# Printing multidimensional array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I just wanna print my empty array by **for** loops.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
```

What is wrong?

```
int NYEARS = 5;
int NRATES = 3;

double[][] balancee = new double[NYEARS][NRATES];
for (int i = 0; i < NYEARS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NRATES; j++) {
        System.out.print(balance[NYEARS][NRATES] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the loop indices to access the array elements, not the array dimensions:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NYEARS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NRATES; j++) {
        System.out.print(balance[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will cause `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` you have also a typo `balance` instead you mean `balancee`:

So Instead you have to use `balancee.length` and `balancee[i].length` and not `balance[NYEARS][NRATES]`, so you have to use `balancee[i][j]` like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < balancee.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < balancee[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(balancee[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: balance[NYEARS][NRATES] this will print only the last value, it is wrong. It is out of bound.

Comment: More importantly, I wonder who gave +1 even if there was a wrong point.

Comment: @snr i think 80% is correct and 10% is wrong so this is why, we are human we make mistakes, we are not angels, i will give you +1 for your comment, you already teaches me something so you deserve +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer generally *foreach* when I don't need making arithmetic operations with their indices

```
for (double[] x : balancee) { 
    for (double y : x) { 
        System.out.print(y + " ");
 }        
    System.out.println(); 
 }
```

More importantly, I hope you get why you cannot use `balance[NYEARS][NRATES]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in `Arrays.deepToString()`

```
int[][] foo = { null, {}, { 1 }, { 2, 3 } };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(foo));
```

Output

```
[null, [], [1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int NYEARS = 5; //This is the size
int NRATES = 3; //This is the size

double[][] balancee = new double[NYEARS][NRATES]; //<-- balancee vs balance



for (int i = 0; i < NYEARS; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < NRATES; j++) {
    System.out.print(balance[NYEARS][NRATES] + " "); //<-- use i and j instead of size. 
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```